Informal Description of a Deterministic Turing Machine for a Specific Language
I'm working on a problem that asks for an informal description of a deterministic Turing Machine (TM) for the following language:
$L=\{a^i b^j a^k b^l | i+j=k+l\}$
The challenge is to describe how a deterministic TM would accept strings in this language, ensuring the condition i+j=k+l holds.
How should I approach designing a deterministic TM for this language? What would be a good informal description of the steps the TM should take? Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

You can build a PDA for the language then construct the TM adapted from the PDA.

Thank you for your response. How would i construct a PDA for this language ?

I recommend to start with cases that look hard. With a word like $a^8b^6$, a nondeterministic machine correctly has $j=0$.

@greybeard We should treat this nondeterministically.

@greybeard I mean we could built a nondeterministic PDA for $L$ to treat your case $jk=0$. Then we base on CYK algorithm to construct a polynomial time TM, $CFL\subseteq P$. I have yet to succeed in finding a way to construct a deterministic PDA.

Try working outside in/using  two deterministic PDAs.

@greybeard Oh, I got it. Two PDAs should use same stack. However, it is another story when the problem is, e.g., $i+2j=3k+4l$, and so on.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
