Informal Description of a Non-Deterministic Turing Machine (NTM) for a Language
I need help describing a Non-Deterministic Turing Machine (NTM) for the following language:
$L=\{(ww^c)^n | n>1$ and $w,w^c\in\{a,b\}^*\}$. If $w=w_1...w_k$ then $w^c=w_1^c...w_k^c$ where $w_i^c=b$ if $w_i=a$ and $w_i^c=a$ if $w_i=b$
How should I approach writing an informal description for this NTM? Any insight into the necessary non-deterministic steps would be really helpful!

You just asked https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/170235/informal-description-of-a-deterministic-turing-machine-for-a-specific-language. This website isn't for doing your homework.

What about a TM recognising a single $ww^c$?

@greybeard thank you for your response, how can we generalize a TM recognizing a single $ww^c$ to a TM recognizing $n$ repetitions of it ?

Can a TM copy a word?

Informal Description of a Non-Deterministic Turing Machine (NTM) for the Language:
The language is given by:
$$
L = \{ (wwc)^n \mid n > 1 \text{ and } w, wc \in \{a, b\}^* \}
$$
Where:

( w ) is a string of symbols from ({a, b}),
( wc ) is a transformation of ( w ) such that:

If ( w_i = a ), then ( wc_i = b ),
If ( w_i = b ), then ( wc_i = a ),


The string consists of repeated patterns of ( (wwc) ), where ( n > 1 ) (i.e., at least two repetitions).

Informal Description of the NTM:

Input:
The NTM takes an input string of symbols from ({a, b}). The input string is expected to be in the form:
$$
   (wwc)^n
   $$
where the machine must verify that the string consists of multiple repetitions of the pattern ( (wwc) ), with ( n > 1 ).

Step 1: Non-Deterministic Guessing of the Split for ( w ):
The NTM will non-deterministically guess the position where the first occurrence of ( w ) ends and the second ( w ) begins. It guesses a boundary, dividing the string into potential segments of ( (wwc) ).

The machine chooses a point to mark the boundary between the first ( w ) and the second ( w ).
This non-deterministic choice is crucial, as it allows the NTM to try different positions for the first ( w ).


Step 2: Checking the Pattern ( ww ):
After the NTM guesses where ( w ) ends, it will check if the second ( w ) matches the first ( w ).

The machine compares the first half of the string (which it believes to be ( w )) with the second part (which it believes to be another occurrence of ( w )).
It ensures that each pair of corresponding characters matches: ( w_1 = w_2, w_3 = w_4, \dots ).


Step 3: Checking the Transformation to ( wc ):
The NTM now verifies that the third part of the string follows the transformation rules to form ( wc ) from ( w ). The transformation rule is as follows:

If ( w_i = a ), then ( wc_i = b ),
If ( w_i = b ), then ( wc_i = a ).

This involves checking that for each character of ( w ), the corresponding character of ( wc ) satisfies the transformation condition.

Step 4: Repeating the Process for Multiple Repetitions:
Since the string is in the form ( (wwc)^n ), where ( n > 1 ), the NTM needs to verify that the pattern repeats multiple times.

The NTM will non-deterministically guess the next boundary (the next position where a new ( (wwc) ) pattern starts).
It repeats Steps 2 and 3 for each new repetition, ensuring that:

The second ( w ) matches the first ( w ),
The corresponding characters in ( wc ) follow the transformation rules.




Step 5: Accept or Reject:

If the NTM successfully verifies all repetitions, it will accept the input string.
If any repetition fails (i.e., the second ( w ) doesn't match the first ( w ), or the transformation rules for ( wc ) are violated), the machine will reject the string.



Summary of Non-Deterministic Steps:

Non-deterministically guess the boundary between the first ( w ) and the second ( w ).
Verify the repetition: Ensure that the second ( w ) matches the first ( w ).
Check the transformation to ( wc ): For each character in ( w ), ensure the corresponding character in ( wc ) follows the transformation rules:

( w_i = a \rightarrow wc_i = b ),
( w_i = b \rightarrow wc_i = a ).


Repeat for subsequent ( (wwc) ) patterns, non-deterministically choosing new boundaries and checking the transformation and repetition rules.
Accept or reject based on whether all repetitions are valid.

Key Insight on Non-Determinism:
The most important non-deterministic step is in Step 1, where the machine guesses where each new repetition of ( (wwc) ) starts. This non-deterministic guess allows the NTM to explore multiple possible ways of dividing the string into repeated ( (wwc) ) patterns. For each guess, the NTM checks the corresponding characters for matching and transformation. If any part of the string doesn’t conform, the machine rejects the input.

I find items numerate twice even more distracting where numbered inconsistently: use 0. for the item before Step 1. Oh, and use \rightarrow & co in a math context(enclose in $\rightarrow$) - or an XML entity: →.
